# Collision of flair bounding boxes and weird alignments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

I don't know if anyone is getting this, but I suspect it's part of what happened two nights ago.  So, [here is an example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37288) of what's happening:

[image: Screen shot of post]

I think it should go away soon, I don't know. Is anyone else having this?

Edit:, I thought it fixed itself, until I went to the Users tab, and this came up:

[image]

My drop down menu is fine, and everything else is fine, but that user tab seems to have a mind of its own.

Comment: What happened two nights ago?

Comment: I thought they moved the site off for maintenance, or something....

Comment: Could you add a link to the post you're referring to as 'what was happening two nights ago?'

Comment: [Croppy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image))

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed on production.

Comment: Jeez, you're fast Jin!

Comment: @M. inb4 twss...

Answer (score 0):

I was testing this in a few browsers (I saw it in Chrome on OS X), but all of a sudden it was corrected.

However, in a user's profile their picture is still framed... badly. I haven't viewed profiles on English.SE before, so I don't know if this is new, but it could be related.

[image]

Comment: Yes, refreshing that page it appears to be fixed.